# "C'aveva" si può scrivere?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ho un grande dubbio. "C'aveva" si può scrivere o viene considerato errore? 
Vorrei sapere se esiste magari un modo più convincente di scrivere la particella rafforzativa in oggetto, che tenta, così apostrofata, di rendere il parlato, ma che mi pare impropria.

Comment: Ciao! Potresti trovare utile [questa risposta](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_380.html).

Comment: La *Prima lezione di grammatica* di Serianni ha nel primo capitolo delle belle pagine su questa e altre questioni di “grammatica del parlato”, in cui prende in esame le diverse possibili grafie («c'aveva», “ci aveva”, “ciaveva”). Personalmente non amo “c'aveva” perché, come osserva anche la pagina segnalata da mrnld, sembra doversi pronunciare “caveva” (e infatti in altri tempi questa grafia si usava per contrarre “che aveva”).

Comment: @DaG: Potresti scrivere quello che spiega Serianni come risposta?

Answer (score 3):

Nel libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* di Vittorio Coletti (Il Mulino, Bologna, 2015) si può leggere questa spiegazione:

> Il problema è anche grafico, come abbiamo visto al capitolo I. Come si scrive *ci* davanti a voci del verbo *avere* che hanno per consuetudine grafica la *h*: «c'ho»?,  «ci ho»? È il caso di tornare alle vecchie *ò/à* della scuola elementare di un tempo, col rischio di scrivere «c'à» o «ci  à», «c'ò» o «ci  ò» (che sembra proprio   «ciò»)? Ma neppure dove non c'è *h* siamo tanto sicuri: «c'aveva» o «ci aveva»? Perché c'è questo problema? Semplicemente perché, essendo questo un uso soprattutto del parlato, non si è ancora consolidata una soluzione grafica. Ma succederà, tranquilli. Nel frattempo scriviamo *ci* intero («ci ho», «ci aveva»), fidandoci del consiglio di Francesco Sabatini (che giudica le altre soluzioni «decisamente inaccettabili»).

Answer (score -4):

"C'aveva" è scorretto. È usato impropriamente nel parlato e nello scritto risulta essere ulteriormente meno opportuno. Usa semplicemente "aveva".

Comment: Qualche fonte da citare? Posso concordare con l'opinione che sia brutto, ma è solo un'opinione e molti scrittori non concordano.